# Which method should I use to check if a host is alive in c++?

Tags: c++, host

I was looking some C++ library/method to check if a host is live in my LAN (and also if a specif port). Thank you in advance !

Comment: If ping is enabled on that host, you can invoke ping it programatically. If your host is running some sort of server, you could connect to it (it will prove life but not death)

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What have you tried so far? Why not just use sockets? Is this the sole purpose of this program? What does `alive` mean (i.e., that it is pingable? That it's listening for TCP connections on a specific port?).

Comment: My idea is to find the host which is connected to my LAN and if their opened ports.

Comment: What is the method for C++, to open a socket to a specif IP and PORT ?

Answer (score 1):

you didnt mention a platfrom. So I will guess linux.

[What is the best method to ping in c++ under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313712/what-is-the-best-method-to-ping-in-c-under-linux)

if windows use the iphelper library - that allows ping

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The platform is on Mac